# echo HTML that contains data from MySQL (whitespace)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, string, echo

I am trying to output a dynamic table, that works with JQuery

Just to get rid of the "" signs I tried declaring another variable:

```
$rowname = $row["name"];
```

And then have that row name saved in the data-bubble, which would be used by JQuery.

```
echo '<tr id='.$current_row.' data-bubble={"part":"'.$rowname.'"}>';
```

The JQuery part:

```
    var bubData=jQuery.parseJSON($(this).attr("data-bubble"));
    console.log(bubData);
    $("#bubbleTable b.part").text(bubData.part);
```

So when I have a 'name' entry (NoSpace) that has no spaces inside it, everything works:

```
<tr id="1" data-bubble={"part":"NoSpace"}>
```

But whenever the name contains a space (Yes Space), this is what i get:
Firefox:

```
<tr id="2" Space"}="" data-bubble={"part":"Yes">
```

IE:

```
<tr id="2" data-bubble='{"part":"Yes' Space"}="">
```

There has to be an easy way to get around this issue, but apparently my specialized English is not as good to find it myself. (Have been searching for quite a while now. Not the right things, I guess.)

Comment: So, this kinda works, but I don't know if its the best way for this.  
  
`$data_bubble_insert = '{"part":"'.$row["name"].'"}';
  printf('<tr id="%d" data-bubble=\'%s\'>', $current_row, $data_bubble_insert);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget the double quote in data-bubble and the browsers interpret the content in different ways.

i suggest you to use printf/sprintf to format a string properly without double quote madness:

```
printf('<tr id="%d" data-bubble="{\'part\':\'%s\'}">', $current_row, $rowname);
```

output:

```
<tr id="1" data-bubble="{'part':'Yes Space'}>"
```

(based on comment) try to invert quoting to avoid problems:

```
printf("<tr id='%d' data-bubble='{\"part\":\"%s\"}'>", $current_row, $rowname);
```

output:

```
<tr id='1' data-bubble='{"part":"Yes Space"}'>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, BUT the JSON is not using it right. It only accepts the double-quotes. So the output has to be {"part":"Yes Space"} 
However, using / (escape) in front of " (double-quotes) doesn't seem to work in the given case. And I have no idea why. :/

Answer (score 0):

Scape the tr string:

```
echo '<tr id='.$current_row.' data-bubble="{\"part\":\"'.$rowname.'\"}";
```

Comment: This doesnt really help.. i already tried that. This will just return:
`<tr id="2" data-bubble='{\"part\":\"Yes' Space\"}="">`

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes after slash 
like '\